# Feign makes empty request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I've use eureka and openfeign and I want to send simple post but it nulls fields in request body.

Below is definition of client

```kotlin
@FeignClient("notification", path = "/api")
interface NotificationClient {

    @RequestMapping(
        method = [RequestMethod.POST],
        path = ["/sms"],
        consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
        name = "sendSms"
    )
    fun sendSms(@RequestBody(required = true) message: Message)
}
```

Body:

```kotlin
@MarkAsOpen
class Message(
    val phone: String,
    val text: String,
    val uuid: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
) {
```

And in other service I've receive error that fields are null

```log
2024-03-19 08:33:00.070 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public void tralalala.notification.sms.control.SmsResource.sendSms(tralalala.sms.Message): [Error in object 'tralalala.sms.Message': codes []; arguments []; default message [Parameter specified as non-null is null: method tralalala.sms.Message.<init>, parameter phone]] ]
```

When I've call this endpoint via external tool it works. Looks like Feign client nulls body.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this. Due to conflict with soap endpoints I had to mark @RequestBody also on Rest endpoint, and now deserialization works fine

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("$API_URI/sms")
    fun sendSms(@RequestBody message: Message) {
        //logic
    }
```